# symfony 1.4 twitter bootstrap login

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony-1.4

I have an old working login form in symfony 1.4.Each field is displayed by using symfony helpers(renderLabel).

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('core/login') ?>" method="post" class="form-signin">
    <div class="alert-error">
    <?php if(!empty($error)): ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error ?></span><br /><br />
    <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Welcome To Company</h2>
    <legend>Please Sign-in</legend>
    <?php echo $form['username']->renderLabel() ?><br />
    <?php echo $form['username'] ?>
    <?php if($form['username']->hasError()): ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $form['username']->getError() ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo $form['password']->renderLabel() ?><br />
    <?php echo $form['password'] ?>
    <?php if($form['password']->hasError()): ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $form['password']->getError() ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login" >Login</button>
   </form>
```

But I like to modify it and add some "handsome" looks so I need to replace the form with this.

```
<h1 class="text-center login-title">Some Company</h1>
               <p class="text-center">Please Sign-in</p>
               <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus >
               <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
               <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">Sign in</button>
```

What are the possible ways in modifying the login form ? I only need to modify the login form .

Answer (score 0):

Got it..I hardcoded it to accomplish..In my loginForm.class.php

```
<?php
class LoginForm extends BaseForm {
public function configure() {
$this->setWidgets(array(
'username'=>new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('size'=>32,               'class'=>'form-controll','placeholder' => 'Username')),
        'password'=>new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('size'=>32, 'class'=>'form-controll','placeholder' => 'Password'))
    ));

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('login[%s]');
    $this->setValidators(array(
        'username'=>new sfValidatorString(array('max_length'=>50)),
        'password'=>new sfValidatorString()
    ));

    $this->widgetSchema->setLabels(array(
        'username'=>'Username',
        'password'=>'Password'
    ));
}
```

}

Then I added a custom css for the form-controll class

```
<style>
 .form-controll{position:relative;font-size:16px;height:auto;-webkit-box-sizing:border-   box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:10px;}
```

.form-controll:focus{z-index:2;}

Then in my templates

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function() { $("#flip").fadeToggle(2000);},2000)
});
</script>
<div class="container" id="divcon">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="account-wall">
            <img class="profile-img" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-  k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=120"
                alt="solidbond">
                <?php if(!empty($error)): ?>
                  <div class="modal-body" id="flip">
                    <?php echo $error ?></div><br /><br />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($form['username']->hasError()): ?>
                   <div class="modal-body" id="flip">
                    <?php echo $form['username']->getError() ?>
                   </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if($form['password']->hasError()): ?>
                   <div class="modal-body" id="flip">
                    <?php echo $form['password']->getError() ?>
                   </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <form action="<?php echo url_for('core/login') ?>" method="post"   class="form-signin">
               <h1 class="text-center login-title">Company</h1>
               <p class="text-center">Please Sign-in</p>
               <?php echo $form['username'] ?><br />
               <?php echo $form['password'] ?><br />
               <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">Sign in</button>   
            <label class="checkbox pull-left">
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                Remember me
            </label>
                <a href="#" class="pull-right need-help">Need help? </a><span   class="clearfix"></span>
             </form>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="text-center new-account">Maintained By: you </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wrote a piece of j Query to separate the form errors in username and password fields..